# How to bound the data from textbox into listview dynamically

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have all the links in the textbox2 but when i click on convert button that link should come in list view .but i cant get the list view with the data.so any one can guidance me

here is my code:

```
 protected void btn_createlink_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var links = TextBox1.Text.Split(new string[] { "\n", "\r" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
           // dt["Links"] = TextBox1.Text;
            foreach (var link in links)
            {
                if (!IsLinkWorking(link))
                {
                    //Here you can show the error. You don't specify how you want to show it.
                    TextBox2.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
                    TextBox2.Text += string.Format("{0}\nNot working\n\n ", link);
                }
                else
                {
                    TextBox2.Text += string.Format("{0}\n working\n\n", link);
                }
            }
        }



    protected void Button2_Click(object sender, 
                                 EventArgs e)[convert button click event]
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("Links");
        dt.Columns.Add("Status");
        dt.Columns.Add("Error");
        dt.AcceptChanges();
        DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr["Links"] = "";
        dr["Status"] = "";
        dr["Error"] = "";
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        dt.AcceptChanges();

        myListView.DataSource = dt;
        myListView.DataBind();

        //var item = string.Format("[{0}, {1} ,{2}]", TextBox2.Text );           
    }
```

client side:

```
<asp:ListView runat="server" ID="myListView">
        <LayoutTemplate>
            <table id="Table1" runat="server" border="1">
                <tr id="Tr1" runat="server">
                    <th id="Th1" runat="server">Links</th>
                    <th id="Th2" runat="server">Status</th>
                    <th id="Th3" runat="server">Error</th>
                </tr>
                <tr runat="server" id="ItemPlaceholder">
                </tr>
            </table>
        </LayoutTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <tr id="Tr2" runat="server">
                <td id="Td1" runat="server"> Eval("Links")</td>
                <td id="Td2" runat="server"> Eval("Status")></td>
                <td id="Td3" runat="server"> Eval("Error")</td>
            </tr>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:ListView>
```

Comment: you don't have to add runat="server" to the TDs and THs inside the listView

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not assign data to the columns of row of `DataTable`. Assign value before adding row to datatable.

*Change*

```
dr["Links"] = "";
dr["Status"] = "";
dr["Error"] = "";
```

*To*

```
dr["Links"] = "some link";
dr["Status"] = "status ";
dr["Error"] = " no error";
```

or

```
dr["Links"] = txtLink.Text;
dr["Status"] = txtStatus.Text;
dr["Error"] = txtError.Text;
```

*Your code would be.*

```
protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)[convert button click event]
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add("Links");
    dt.Columns.Add("Status");
    dt.Columns.Add("Error");
    dt.AcceptChanges();
    DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
    dr["Links"] = "some link";
    dr["Status"] = "status ";
    dr["Error"] = " no error";
    dt.Rows.Add(dr);
    dt.AcceptChanges();
    myListView.DataSource = dt;
    myListView.DataBind();
    //var item = string.Format("[{0}, {1} ,{2}]", TextBox2.Text );           
}
```

Comment: yes you got my problem but how can i assign that links are in textbox2 and error to is in the textbox2

Comment: You probably need to assign the text of your textbox like, dr["Links"] = txtLink.Text;

Comment: bro in the listview output is Eval("Links")|Eval("Status")|.... so is their need to change something in  <td id="Td1" runat="server"> Eval("Links")</td>
                <td id="Td2" runat="server"> Eval("Status")></td>
                <td id="Td3" runat="server"> Eval("Error")</td>

Comment: but how that should be done,what should i pass so that my links can be bound into listview instead Eval("links")

Comment: When you call  myListView.DataBind(); it will be done automatically.

Comment: its not happening bro..wait i am editing my code and also including my links which is in textbox2 so you can suggest my to what should i change

Comment: You are still assigning empty string to columns, dr["Links"] = "";

Comment: dr["Links"] = txtLink.Text; where to assign this

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26222/discussion-between-hitarth-and-adil)

Answer (score 2):

I did some modification, please let me know if this works.

```
<asp:ListView runat="server" ID="myListView">
        <LayoutTemplate>
            <table id="Table1" runat="server" border="1">
                <tr id="Tr1" runat="server">
                    <th id="Th1" runat="server">
                        Links
                    </th>
                    <th id="Th2" runat="server">
                        Status
                    </th>
                    <th id="Th3" runat="server">
                        Error
                    </th>
                </tr>
                <tr runat="server" id="ItemPlaceholder">
                </tr>
            </table>
        </LayoutTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <tr id="Tr2" runat="server">
                <td id="Td1" runat="server">
                    <%#Eval("Links") %>
                </td>
                <td id="Td2" runat="server">
                    <%#Eval("Status")%>
                </td>
                <td id="Td3" runat="server">
                    <%#Eval("Error")%>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:ListView>




DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("Links");
        dt.Columns.Add("Status");
        dt.Columns.Add("Error");
        dt.AcceptChanges();
        DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr["Links"] = "a";
        dr["Status"] = "b";
        dr["Error"] = "c";
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        dt.AcceptChanges();

        myListView.DataSource = dt;
        myListView.DataBind();
```

Comment: sorry still same output "Eval("Links")" that is only displayed

Comment: use  <%#Eval("Links") %>  in place of  Eval("Links")

Comment: in your client side code you written as Eval("Links") this will display Eval("Links") when you will view in browser

Comment: if you use <%#Eval("Links") %> it will show "a" as i written in above code.Hope This helps.

Comment: yes thanks but i want the links instead of a,b,c,can you suggest me

Comment: I think you are assigning dr["Links"] = "http://google.com" then to get link use <%#"<a href="+ Eval("Links")+">Test</a>"%> in place of <%#Eval("Links") %>